# Bar chart using function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

First off, i would like to say that i'm sorry if this is obvious, i have only recently started using LaTeX.

I want to create a bar-plot that looks something like this:
[image]

I would, of course, like to use the function at the top of the image instead of having to manually write the coordinates of every bar. I can't seem to make PGFplots use my function when i try to display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome. Such plots can be obtained with `ybar` plots from `pgfplots`. My problem is that the values I get are nowhere close to what you seem to get, but up to the normalization this comes rather close.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=14cm,height=6cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
        domain=1950:2012,xmin=1948,xmax=2014,
        samples=63,bar width=2pt,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,font=\tiny,
        /pgf/number format/set thousands separator=},
        xtick={1950,1951,...,2012}
    ]
    \addplot {6029.7*pow(1.031,x)/(6.72*x+259.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can adjust the normalization by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=14cm,height=6cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=6029.7*pow(1.031,\x)/(6.72*\x+259.4);}]
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
        domain=1950:2012,xmin=1948,xmax=2014,
        ymin=19,ymax=64,
        samples=63,bar width=3pt,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,font=\small,
        /pgf/number format/set thousands separator=},
        xtick={1950,1952,...,2012},
        ytick={20,30,...,70},minor y tick num=4,
        yminorgrids,ymajorgrids,
        title={$\displaystyle\frac{P(t)}{N(t)}=\frac{6029.7\cdot 1.031^t}{6.72\,t+259.4}$},
        title style={anchor=north,at={(0.5,0.95)},fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot {f(x)*47/f(2012)+15};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason that you don't get the same numbers is because mine is actually showing the domain `0:62` and i have instead just changed the value of each x-tick. Is there a simple way to achieve this without having to hype each year underneath?

Comment: Also, what does this command do? `/pgf/number format/set thousands separator=},`

Comment: @Hartvig1 `/pgf/number format/set thousands separator=` sets the thousands separator to nothing so that you get `1952`, and not `1,952`.